# ImageMagick read pdf ignores Width

Tags: .net, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I'm trying to read a pdf with ImageMagick, by using the following code:

```
using (var images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    var settings = new MagickReadSettings
    {
        ColorSpace = ColorSpace.RGB,
        Format = MagickFormat.Pdf,
        Compression = CompressionMethod.NoCompression,
        Width = 3000
    };
    images.Read(inputFilePath, settings);
}
```

but the Width parameter seems to be ignored.
I need an output size which is independent from pdf resolution/density.
Would it be possible?
Thanks